# Normal Squash Instructions Not Showing Expected Commits

Tags: git, squash

I am having a squashing problem.  I have reviewed similar questions, but they don't seem to fit.

When I do a git status, I get:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/mutual_19.2.1' by 2 commits.
```

When I do `git log` it shows me:

```
commit 9be1847ec8d9b472f99e362b266ec18fc73470dd
Merge: 67eb216 5bee872
Author: jsmith <john.smith@acme.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 15 12:57:21 2019 -0500

Merge branch 'mutual_19.2.1' of ssh://cm1.mutual.us.vector.com:29418/Data_Delivery into Ticket_7503

Change-Id: I8d39d66d9d7a3933cb49bfc7f114e460aa141b5c

commit 67eb216fee18aecf6458a84bf9863901336b10a8
Author: jsmith <john.smith@acme.com>
Date:   Fri Jan 4 09:53:15 2019 -0500

Mutual #7503 - Remove subscription grouping capabilities.

Change-Id: I8d39d66d9d7a3933cb49bfc7f114e460aa141b5c
```

which is what I would expect, it shows both the conflict merge that I did and the changes I want to push.  Per the instructions for a squash that I find, I do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

However, this shows me

```
pick 67eb216 Mutual #7503 - Remove subscription grouping capabilities.
pick 0749a12 Mutual #7330 - Made latency for PDA subscriptions editable.
pick 0ab8c6e Mutual #7504 - Close Subset dialog on subscription creation.
```

which is almost completely different from the above.

What is causing this, and how can I squash the commits I want to squash?

Comment: The top commit is a merge commit, and therefore has 2 parents. Thus, `HEAD~2` resolves to 2 commits in your interactive rebase.

Comment: `git rebase` ignores merges by default, merges "should" only apply changes already in their parents and any conflict resolutions may not be correct for the new base. Those three commits aren't in `HEAD~2`'s history and are in `HEAD`'s.  You don't need to supply the count, rebase defaults to the upstream, your command is just `git rebase`.  If you really  do just want to squash everything, do `git reset --hard @{u}; git merge --squash @{1}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your branch/fork is not synced with master/upstream.

If you are working on a fork :

```
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/develop or git rebase upstream/master (which ever is the branch for which you want to make a pull request) 
git push origin <your-branch-name> -f
```

If you are working on a branch within the same repository:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/develop or git rebase origin/master (which ever is the branch for which you want to make a pull request) 
git push origin <your-branch-name> -f
```

Then do a git log and then git rebase -i HEAD~2